# VBA Excel- Replicating Excel MAX formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to replicate the following excel formula without using constants in VBA

```
 =MAX(A9:A13)
 =MAX(A4:A8,A14:A18)
```

wherein the selection start and end (A9) and (A13) is a dynamic cell(not limited to A column) and is stored in the variables startVar and endVar.

For =MAX(A9:A13) I did the following code

```
 startVar = "A9"
 endVar = "A14"

 Range(startVar, endVar).Select
 Range("B1").Value = Application.Max(Selection)
```

Using the code above, how do I replicate =MAX(A4:A8,A4:A18) while still using the variables startVar and endVar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("B1").Value = WorksheetFunction.MAX(Range(StartVar & ":" & EndVar))`

The `WorksheetFunction` collection lets you use most of the Excel functions as VBA functions.

Comment: how about for =MAX(A4:A8,A4:A18)? without selecting cells A1 to A3 and while replacing the constants with variables?

Comment: Isn't that the same as saying `MAX(A4:A18)`?  But, if you wanted `MAX(A4:A8, A10:A18)` then you would just do `WorksheetFunction.MAX(Range("A4:A8"), Range("A10:A18"))` - it's exactly the same as in Excel, but you use `Range` objects as the cells.  You should *probably* be specifying the worksheet too: `WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.Range("A1:B5"))` (otherwise Excel will guess, and probably get it wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Try a Union of the two discontiguous ranges.

```
Range("B1").Value = Application.Max(Union(Range("A4:A8"), Range("A14:A18")))
'alternate
Range("B1").Value = Application.Max(Range("A4:A8, A14:A18"))

dim maxarr as variant
maxarr = array(4, 8, 14, 18)
Range("B1").Value = Application.Max(Range(cells(maxarr(0), "A"), cells(maxarr(1), "A")), _
                                    Range(cells(maxarr(2), "A"), cells(maxarr(3), "A")))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as you use a valid range address.

```
startVar = "A4:A8"
endVar = "A14:A18"

If InStr(startVar & endVar, ":") <> 0 Then sep  = "," Else sep = ":"
Range("B1").Value2 = Application.Max(Range(startVar & sep & endvar))
```

Answer (score 0):

For numeric and `Range` values `WorksheetFunction.Max` will work with multiple params.

Otherwise one has to write it himself and that's my solution which works for `Integer`, `Double`, `String`, `Range` with two params and likely other types (feel free to extend for > 2 params):

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/63013689/1915920
Function Max(a As Variant, Optional b As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeName(a) = "Range" Then Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(a, b): Exit Function
    If a > b Then Max = a Else Max = b
End Function


'https://stackoverflow.com/a/63013689/1915920
Function Min(a As Variant, Optional b As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeName(a) = "Range" Then Min = WorksheetFunction.Min(a, b): Exit Function
    If a < b Then Min = a Else Min = b
End Function
```

test code:

```
Sub test_Max()

    'max int
    Debug.Assert Max(1, 2) = 2
    Debug.Assert Max(2, 1) = 2
    Debug.Assert Max(1, 1) = 1
    
    'max double
    Debug.Assert Max(1, 2.3) = 2.3  

    'max string
    Debug.Assert Max("a", "b") = "b"

    'max ranges
    Dim wb As Workbook:  Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        .range("A1") = 1
        .range("B1") = 2
        .range("C1") = Max(.range("A1"), .range("B1"))
        Debug.Assert .range("C1") = 2
        .range("A2") = 1
        .range("B2") = 2.3
        .range("C2") = Max(.range("A2"), .range("B2"))
        Debug.Assert .range("C2") = 2.3
        .range("C3") = Max(.range("A1", "B2"))
        Debug.Assert .range("C3") = 2.3
    End With
    wb.Close False

    'min
    Debug.Assert Min(2, 1) = 1
    Debug.Assert Min(1, 1) = 1
End Sub
```